# Weird Symbols Are written in output.txt file of C program

Tags: c, io

I am new to C and I am writing a program that will ask users for strings and write them to a file. If no such file is present, it will create the file and then start writing.

The Problem is, along with input strings, weird symbols are being written into the output file. I cannot seem to figure out why. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<fcntl.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char buffer[80];
  char str[20];
  int result;
    fd = open("output.txt",O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
     FILE *fp;
    fp  = fopen ("output.txt", "w");    
      fd = open("output.txt",O_RDWR);
    
    }while(1){
    printf("Enter String: \n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    result=strcmp(str,"-1");
    if(result>=0){
      write(fd, str, sizeof(str));
          printf(" %s was written to output.txt \n", str); 
    }else{
      break;
    }
    
    }
        
}
```

I have also attached the image of my output.txt file. This is what is written when I give, "first", "second" and "third" as input strings.

[image: This is what is written when I give, "first", "second" and "third" as input strings]

Comment: You should clearly adapt to some sane code formatting. `}while(1){` That is highly confusing formatting. Also proper indentation is important. Readability matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
write(fd, str, sizeof(str));
```

That will write all 20 bytes of `str` into the file. Including any unintialised garbage data after the string that was stored into that buffer. Change to:

```
write(fd, str, strlen(str));
```